# Use public CloudKit database (NSPersistentCloudkitContainer) - macOS

Tags: core-data, swiftui, cloudkit, xcode12

I’ve written an iOS app in SwiftUI (using the SwiftUI life cycle in Xcode 12) that uses my CloudKit container’s public database with the following lines of code:

```
 let container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "my_ios_container_name")
    
 guard let description = container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first else {
     print("Can't set description")
     fatalError("Error")
 }
    
 description.cloudKitContainerOptions?.databaseScope = .public
```

I’m in the process of writing a macOS app in SwiftUI that accesses the same CloudKit container’s public database. But when I try to build the code below in my mac app's `AppDelegate.swift` file, Xcode gives me an error saying that it’s unable to find the ‘databaseScope’ member. Is this member variable only available for iOS apps? If this is the case, how do you access a Cloudkit container's public database in a macOS app?

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is available only on iOS, so just wrap it into availability condition for iOS only, if you want to set that description option.

Comment: Thank you! My macOS app’s functionality is dependent on accessing the public database, so is my only option wait until Apple adds this?

Comment: I guess you can access the public database from your macOS app without using the NSPersistentCloudKitContainer. You can just fetch the CKRecords from CKContainer.default.publicCloudDatabase.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding "import CloudKit" to the top of the file.

Resolved this issue for me.